# Function overloading in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In [John Resig tutorial on Javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#90), there's a code used for function overloading, which I couldn't figure out how it works :

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn){
  // Save a reference to the old method
  var old = object[ name ];

  // Overwrite the method with our new one
  object[ name ] = function(){
    // Check the number of incoming arguments,
    // compared to our overloaded function
    if ( fn.length == arguments.length )
      // If there was a match, run the function
      return fn.apply( this, arguments );

    // Otherwise, fallback to the old method
    else if ( typeof old === "function" )
      return old.apply( this, arguments );
  };
}

function Ninjas(){
  var ninjas = [ "Dean Edwards", "Sam Stephenson", "Alex Russell" ];
  addMethod(this, "find", function(){
    return ninjas;
  });
  addMethod(this, "find", function(name){
    var ret = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < ninjas.length; i++ )
      if ( ninjas[i].indexOf(name) == 0 )
        ret.push( ninjas[i] );
    return ret;
  });
  addMethod(this, "find", function(first, last){
    var ret = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < ninjas.length; i++ )
      if ( ninjas[i] == (first + " " + last) )
        ret.push( ninjas[i] );
    return ret;
  });
}
```

1. Why the second `addMethod` doesn't over write the first one ?
2. Why do we need to keep a reference to `old` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your questions answer one another. The second `addMethod` *does overwrite* the first `find` *with a closure*, that thanks to the `old` object containing the first `find`, is able to fall back to it in case the 2nd `find` mismatches the argument count.

When the *third* call to `addMethod` is done, it's basically doing the same thing, *recursively*. So it overwrites *the closure* with another closure, where `old` is the object of which the function `find` is a closure with the 2nd find and the old `old` object containing the 1st `find`. Phew.

Here's an approximate graphic representation:

```
find -> [ find3  ]
        [ old2 --]--> [ find2  ]
                      [ old1 --]--> [ find1 ]
                                    [ null  ]
```

Comment: But after the third `addMethod` is called , we have `this.find` pointing to a function , which inside of it , `fn` expects 2 parameters in the argument , and old expects 1 parameter in the argument. What happens to the case where there's no argument. How is that handled ?